# Custom filter is not executing in jsf portal

Tags: servlet-filters, websphere-portal

I am trying to add a filter to my application which is build with java 6, jsf 2.0, jsr 286, WebSphere_Portal 8.0, primefaces 3.4.2.

my addition to **portlet.xml** is

```html
<filter>
   <filter-name>CustomFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.filter.CustomFilter</filter-class>
   <lifecycle>ACTION_PHASE</lifecycle>
 </filter>
 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CustomFilter</filter-name>
    <portlet-name>UploadFileDemo</portlet-name>
 </filter-mapping>
```

my filter class is **CustomFilter.java**

```js
    package com.filter;
    import javax.portlet.ActionFilter;
    public class CustomFilter implements ActionFilter {
@Override
     public void destroy() {
     System.out.println("destroy");
     }
@Override
     public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws PortletException {
     System.out.println("custom filter initiated");
     }
@Override
     public void doFilter(ActionRequest arg0, ActionResponse arg1,FilterChain arg2) throws IOException, PortletException {
     System.out.println("doFilter method is called");
      }
    }
```

when i deploy the application and submit the form, i am not seeing any SOP of init() and doFilter() method of CustomeFilter class.

Comment: How is this question java-se (does it need a main?), jsf  or primefaces related (other than you using all this)

Comment: Its a web application running on WebSphere_portal

Comment: Yes I know, but unless you can demonstrate this problem in a java class with a main, it is not java--se related. And there is NO jsf or primefaces code visible in your question. So they are notrelated to your problem as your question is now

Comment: can you post the rest of your portlet.xml?